# Symfony 2.8 Monolog rotating_file - prevent generation of prod.log file

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8, monolog

My prod.log file is getting very large, so I want to use the rotating_file option to create one file per day (max 14). It works, everyday a new file is generated but the file prod.log still exists and logs all new messages. Is it possible to prevent the generation of prod.log file? I use Symfony 2.8, monolog 1.23.0 and the default configuration in config.yml:

```
monolog:
    use_microseconds: false
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  rotating_file
            path:  '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
            level: error
            max_files: 14
```

Comment: Have you checked that this configuration is not overwritten in `config_dev.yml` or `config_prod.yml` ?

Comment: Yes, it's only defined in config.yml

Comment: and what about the level ? Maybe Monolog outputs everything that is below `error` level in the  `prod.log` file ? Try lowering it to `debug` and see if it helps

Comment: I also tried that, to be sure - I tried again but same thing. When I delete both files (prod.log and for example prod-2017-11-10.log), both files will be generated with same log messages.

Comment: It looks like you have two handlers existing at the same time though. Try `bin/console debug:container --parameters --env=prod` to see if you have different handlers that would produce this behaviour

Comment: Strange cache behaviour. Answered my own question. I tried your command but could only run it with env=dev... anyway. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I disabled full monolog configuration, cleared both caches, reenabled the configuration, cleared cache again, now it works. Strange cache problem, seems both configurations were used.